# How to use V1/products to get the stockItem qty of the magento products?

Tags: magento2, api, magento-2.0

I need to know for each product sky, price and stock.
I am using `http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`

In the web documentation I see that I can get it

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#!/catalogProductRepositoryV1

```
"stockItem": {
          "itemId": 0,
          "productId": 0,
          "stockId": 0,
          "qty": 0,
          "isInStock": true,
          "isQtyDecimal": true,
          "showDefaultNotificationMessage": true,
          "useConfigMinQty": true,
          "minQty": 0,
          "useConfigMinSaleQty": 0,
          "minSaleQty": 0,
          "useConfigMaxSaleQty": true,
          "maxSaleQty": 0,
          "useConfigBackorders": true,
          "backorders": 0,
          "useConfigNotifyStockQty": true,
          "notifyStockQty": 0,
          "useConfigQtyIncrements": true,
          "qtyIncrements": 0,
          "useConfigEnableQtyInc": true,
          "enableQtyIncrements": true,
          "useConfigManageStock": true,
          "manageStock": true,
          "lowStockDate": "string",
          "isDecimalDivided": true,
          "stockStatusChangedAuto": 0,
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        },
```

But when I use it does not appear that information, why?

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way, i hope this helps you:

```
$api = new Api();
$adminUrl='https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "{your_username}", "password" => "{your_pw}");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$qty = $_GET["qty"];
$sku = $_GET["sku"];

//you need to replace this with your own code for token
$token = $api->GetToken($ch,$data_string);

$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token");
$requestUrl='https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/stockItems/' . $sku;

//See method "GetProductAsObject" below
$product = $api->GetProductAsObject($sku,$ch,$requestUrl,$headers);

$product->qty=$qty;
$product->is_in_stock=true;

$toencode["stockItem"] = $product;

//This part will print your desired result
echo json_encode($toencode);

//#### Info: this method is in a separate class ###
//This method is in the Class Api.php known as $api above
public function GetProductAsObject($sku,$ch,$requestUrl,$headers)
{
     $ch = curl_init();
     $ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     return json_decode($result);
}
```